# How should I secure the Private Key when using Asymmetric RSA encryption?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I am using the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and C#.  I have a web server (A) that will be encrypting data and storing it in a database.  I have another server (B) that will be reading the encrypted data and decrypting it.  The private key will only ever live on server B.

I would like to limit private key access to my application and a very short list of domain users.

What is the best way to store the key so that it is safe from compromise by an unauthorized person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Windows [RSA Key containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5cs0acs.aspx) to store the key.  The key can be installed / created by the [aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28VS.80%29.aspx) tool that ships with the .NET framework.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a walkthrough.

The two options to look out for are:

`-pi` (installs a key to the RSA container)

`-pa` (managements permissions for the key)

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer, this was very helpful.  I knew about RSA Key Containers but I didn't think to use aspnet_regiis to create and store a key -- perfect!